# Error 404 Nginx can't find media files. +Django

Tags: django, linux, nginx, http-status-code-404, media

I was setting up basic Django site with nginx. When i navigate to the url of the file i get error 404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

This is the conf file

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/jo/testproject/testproject.sock;
}
# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # Django media and static files
    location /media/  {
    alias /home/jo/testproject/media/;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/jo/testproject/static;
    }

    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/jo/testproject/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

the media folder is in /home/jo/testproject/media and inside it i have media.gif, but ip/media/media.gif doesnt work

when i write the ip in the browser i get

Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

I think everything else i setup correctly

Answer (score 1):

**Docker + NGINX + Gunicorn + Django**

Django project:

```
djangoapp
 - ...
 - media
 - static
 - manage.py
 - requirements.txt  
nginx
 - Dockerfile
 - nginx.conf 
docker-compose.yml  
Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBUG 0

# https://hub.docker.com/r/fnndsc/ubuntu-python3/dockerfile
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip gunicorn

RUN mkdir /app

COPY djangoapp/requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY djangoapp /app/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn3", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "djangoapp.wsgi:application", "--workers=2"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    container_name: djangoapp1
    volumes:
      - .:/djangoapp
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=8.43.162.54
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes: 
      - .:/djangoapp
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    restart: always

networks: 
  default:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  media:
  static:
```

nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $SERVER_NAME;

    location /static/ {     
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {      
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://djangoapp1:8000;
    }
}
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1):

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/inventory.conf

the upstream component nginx needs to connect to

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/user/Inventory-System/inventory.sock;
}

#configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name trading.code www.trading.code;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    # Django media and static files
    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias home/user/Inventory-System/media/;
    }

location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias home/user/Inventory-System/static/;
}
# Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include    home/user/Inventory-System/uwsgi_params;
} }
```

then

> user@user: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo rm default 
> user@user: $ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

finally

> check http://127.0.0.0/media/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and I add this in my  sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/project file

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name 45.76.42.234;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location  /static/ {
        root /home/django/Django_tutorials/21_Django-deployment;
    }

    location  /media/ {
        root /home/django/Django_tutorials/21_Django-deployment;
    }
    location /Images/ {
          alias /home/django/Django_tutorials/21_Django-deployment/Images/;
    }
}
```

where Images is my image folder that contains uploaded images